# SQL Error Status: 90057 org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Constraint "PRIMARY KEY | UNIQUE (PID, PARTNER)" not found

Tags: h2

I've just upgraded h2database from 1.4.197 to 2.1.212 and now I get an error message for one of my tables that are created when running the tests.

Error:

`org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Constraint "PRIMARY KEY | UNIQUE (PID, PARTNER)" not found; SQL statement: ... [90057-212]`

Status Code: `90057`

SQL File:

```
drop table if exists prov;

create table prov(
    id bigint generated by default as identity(start with 1) not null primary key,
    pid bigint not null,
    parent_id bigint,
    partner varchar(255),
    constraint unique_uk unique(pid, parent_id, partner),
    constraint foreign_fk foreign key (parent_id, partner) references prov(pid, partner)
);
```

This SQL file was working without a problem before upgrading the h2database to v2.1.212.
What should the query be changed with?

I've searched the status code from the error and it seems that this error is thrown when trying to drop a constraint. But I'm not quite sure If I'm actually dropping any constraints. The only thing I'm dropping is the table provider if it exists.

I'm not quite familiar with H2 databases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing specific to H2 database, every sane database system should reject this definition, but old versions of H2 and some other database systems are less restrictive.

Referential constraints require primary key or unique constraint on referenced columns. You already have a unique constraint on `(pid, parent_id, partner)` columns, but your referential constraint `foreign_fk` references only `(pid, partner)`, so something is wrong in definition of your table.

Most likely you need an additional unique constraint on `(pid, partner)`.